# Using the WooCommerce Settings API, how can I filter or add errors to settings values?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The [WooCommerce Settings API documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/settings-api/) gives just enough information to get settings added to Gateway/Shipping Method screens.

However, unlike the native WordPress Settings API, there are no documented "sanitize" callbacks, like WordPress' `register_setting()` has. Thus, if invalid content is supplied, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to be able to use `add_settings_error` or similar.

How am I *supposed* to do this, and what documentation did I overlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where it's documented (if at all) but I found an answer in code:

`woocommerce/classes/abstracts/abstract-wc-settings-api.php` ~ 651 (in 2.0ish) has the following code:

```
// Look for a validate_FIELDID_field method for special handling
if ( method_exists( $this, 'validate_' . $k . '_field' ) ) {
    $field = $this->{'validate_' . $k . '_field'}( $k );
    $this->sanitized_fields[ $k ] = $field;
```

Which means that if you added a setting with something like this:

```
'username' => array(
    'title' => __( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ),
    'type' => 'text',
    'description' => __( 'Please enter your Payment Gateway Username; this is required for taking payments!', 'woocommerce' ),
    'default' => ''
),
```

Then you'd need to add a method on the same payment gateway class called `validate_username_field`, that takes a single argument (the setting value; in this case the username) and returns the sanitized value and/or creates an error.

E.g.,

```
public function validate_username_field($value)
{
    if (...)
    {
        // Valid username!
        return $value;
    } else {
        // Invalid? 
        add_settings_error(...); 
    }
}
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: Did the trick for me, although add_settings_error() does not display anything. WP is 4.7.5 and WC is 3.0.7 any thoughts?